# Is there a way to clear the entire database in the websql or indexed database ?

Tags: web-sql

Consider this - I have created database in websql, inside which, multiple tables are created and encrypted data are loaded on these tables.

By any chance is there way the intruder or any other person can delete the entire database in the websql or clear the entire websql, and if so, how do I protect my database, or provide any password protection to database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're talking about WebSQL or not but if you are - you shouldn't be storing any sensitive data client side anyway.

WebSQL is a SQLite db file that gets saved in a user/appdata folder on the client.

Anyone can navigate to that directory on your computer and open the SQLite file in SQLite Manager or through the terminal and hack away.

If you're storing sensitive data that is encrypted, it should be stored server side in a protected zone.

To part of your question:

If a malicious user deletes the webSQL db?

Then it should be recreated the next time the user navigates to the website and populated with server data.

The data stored client side can be compromised and should only be trusted with a validated session for the lifetime of the session.